# Change color of DataTables search bar

Tags: html, datatables

I have a dark background on my webpage, so when I implement DataTables into my project, the search bar is barely visible. I import the scripts instead of directly having the source code for DataTables in my project, so I can't change the color of the search bar there.

How might I change the color from black to white? This is what it looks like at the moment:
[image]

Here is my code, I'm using Razor Pages

```
@page
@model CustomerPageTest.Pages.Customer.ListModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "List";
}

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').dataTable({
                "paging": false,
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: -1,
                    className: 'dt-head-center'
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">





<h1 align="center" style="color:yellowgreen">1) Select/Add Customer</h1>

<br />
<div>
    <p align="center">
        <a class="btn btn-dark"
           asp-page="/Index"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Back</a>
        <a class="btn btn-dark"
           asp-page="./AddCustomer"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  Add New Customer</a>
        <a class="btn btn-dark"
           asp-page="./ListAssessments"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  Use Existing Assessment</a>
    </p>
</div>

<table id="myTable" class="display cell-border stripe" role="grid" style="background-color: #dbdbdb; text-align:center; width: 100%">
    <thead class="text-light">
        <tr class="text-dark">
            <th style="text-align: center"><strong>Customer</strong></th>
            <th style="text-align: center"><strong>Notes</strong></th>
            <th style="text-align: center"><strong>New Assessment</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="background-color: #dbdbdb;">
        @foreach (var customer in Model.Customers)
        {
            <tr class="text-dark">
                <td style="padding-top: 15px">@customer.name</td>
                <td style="padding-top: 15px">@customer.notes</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-dark"
                       asp-page="/Assessment/AddAssessment" asp-route-customerId="@customer.customer_id">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: Found the class and id that links to the search bar, added new definitions into the CSS to try and overwrite it, but no new results...

Here is a screenshot of the Inspect:
[image]

And the CSS code I have added:

```
/*Change Search Bar to White*/
.myTable_filter {
    color: white;
}

#dataTables_filter {
    color: white;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Attach your html and css code as snippet.

Comment: @Derek.W done, sorry completely blanked on doing that

Comment: no search bar on the code...

Comment: @Derek.W  In the description, I said I was using scripts

Comment: Then the only way is to inspect the page and select that `select-box` and see the styles there, and overwrite it on your css.

Comment: @Derek.W Would I just create a CSS class with the same name as the one I find in inspecting the page?

Comment: Yeah, that's the only way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222981/discussion-between-ckneeland-and-derek-w).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `search-box` on `dataTable` seems to be generated by the package script.

So you can change the background color of `input` tag by overriding the css style only.

Based on `inspect` screenshot, this will work.

```
#myTable_wrapper .dataTables_filter input {
  background-color: white;
}
```